# is it possible to designate a text rectangle with Paint?

Tags: android, canvas, paint

I'm drawing text into a Canvas and want to assign a rectangle so that the text breaks and goes to the next line if it reaches the right hand boundary.  There's an "align" property I can set, so clearly the notion of a right side and middle exists but I can't figure out how to designate what the width of the text box should be.

TIA

EDIT...
I'm getting the sense that I'm going to have to roll my own line break insertion method that utilizes the Paint.breakText method.  I'm *really hoping that's not the case! :)

edit2..
So on top of everything else, drawText ignores the \n and draws it as a [] missing char.

I've written a workaround that moves the origin point of the text down for each line, but BOY is this ugly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paint.getTextBounds returns your string width by

"Return in bounds (allocated by the caller) the smallest rectangle that encloses all of the characters, with an implied origin at (0,0)."

I think most likely you will need to draw the string manually by yourself

Comment: yeah... that appears to be the case... oh well... I'll post my code when I'm done, in case someone else finds it useful

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [`StaticLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/StaticLayout.html) instead of trying to break the text yourself. It has provision for line wrapping. To quote from the docs:

> You should not need to use this class directly unless you are implementing your own widget or custom display object, or would be tempted to call [`Canvas.drawText()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawText%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) directly.

Comment: how do I draw a StaticLayout into my Canvas?  I'm actually outputting a Bitmap (adding text to a photo that the user has taken). So, unless I'm misunderstanding you, I don't think this solution applies.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel - The parent `Layout` class defines a `draw(Canvas)` method. You will need to translate the canvas origin to where you want the layout to be drawn.